# asp.net webapp - is viewdata safe for local request variable?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, razor-pages, viewdata

**What is my need -**
I have a .net7.0 asp.net-webapp (razor). There are some parts of my cshtml that i want to customise based on per request which will be determined by c# corresponding PageModel class code.

**What i did -** 
1 - using class static variables.
Result - blunder. got to know they are same for all users so it would have broken site functionality.
2 - using cookies
Result - cookies can only be appended to response and read on request, so data can't be transferred within one request but it is good for transferring data across requests.
3 - Viewdata["name"]
Result - found good for my need. the data is available only for that request.
**What i want to know -**
1 - Does the data in viewdata get destroyed after request ends or it piles up in server's memory.
2 - Is it safe to use viewdata in this way. Is there anything i should keep in mind while using it so it can be secure, doesn't load the server and provides needed functionality.

Comment: The view data objects which stored the data only exists during the current request. So, the data in viewdata get destroyed after request ends . ViewData is a container for data to be passed from the PageModel to the content page. What do you mean about "doesn't load the server and provides needed functionality." ?

Comment: @QingGuo it means that the data of the variable doesn't exist after the request ends or otherwise it will load(as in lag or reduce efficiency) of server. sorry for my grammar it should be doesn't put much load on the server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't actually given any details of what your need is, but in answer to the main question, ViewData is not stored across requests. It is a property of the PageModel, which is instantiated with each request and destroyed once the request has been processed and the response generated.

ViewData is used for passing data to views/pages. It is not strongly typed and can be error prone. For that reason, it is recommended to use public properties of the PageModel for passing data to views/pages. ViewData's primary use case is for passing data to weakly-typed Layout pages.

https://www.learnrazorpages.com/razor-pages/viewdata

Comment: well i don't need strongly typed data to be passed. its all values and not anything including html tags. so viewdata it is.